Mixing up UML and non-UML diagrams
When designing a data-intensive software, or any kind of software, regardless of the platform, is it appropriate to mix UML and non-UML diagrams together in the design document of the software?
For example, is it ok to use the use-case diagram and class diagram, then use ERD for the database?
Put another way, if one would like to use UML diagrams, must he/she use UML diagrams exclusively? would it be an error (or frown upon) to include another diagram type with UML diagrams?

It is constitutionally impermissible to mix UML diagrams with other diagrams in the same design document. Violations are punishable by house arrest for no less than 10 years.

... I hope you have some sense of humor and got the message. Still you are asking the wrong people - it is only your audience who can tell you what form of documents they prefer - strangers from the internet don't know your audience.

@DocBrown you scared me! Haha but seriously, I heard some knowledgeable people say its like violating the syntax of a programming language. If it's a matter of preference, then that's not a problem, right?

It it is a matter of preference of your audience. Think for whom you are writing the design documents. Some people or organizations are dogmatic about it, others are quite libreral. If your "audience" is a code generator, choosing the wrong diagram type might not allow to use it. And using UML and non-UML diagrams isn't like violating the syntax of a programming language, it is more like using two different languages within one system (which is not uncommon).

Understood. But lets assume the audience does not have any specific preference regarding the diagrams, would UML practitioners frow upon usage of non-UML diagrams with UML diagrams in the same design document? As a general practice is this acceptable? Does the UML specification say anything about this?

What I wrote about some people being dogmatic and others more liberal applies to "UML practitioners" as well. And no, the UML spec does not say anything about this.

Design documentation is meant for people. Machines don't care. People care because these documents help them build the system or maintain it. Worse case scenario, the documents are a box-ticking exercise mandated by some organizations because someone said "best practice."
The documents communicate something, and they should have a clearly defined audience and a purpose. Use whatever form of documentation your audience finds useful. There is no law, standard, or rule that mandates one and only one kind of document. Just like everything else an engineer uses, diagrams and documents are tools. Use them when appropriate. Don't use them if they aren't beneficial (unless it is a box-ticking exercise because someone said "best practice").
For clarity, the UML specification describes how to create UML diagrams. It does not prescribe when they are mandatory. That is a "people" and "organizational" decision.

I'd add: when you mix, just make clear at the diagrams what what means so people don't have to pull up a separate documentation about how to read the documentation. (And depending on audience that also might mean to put a short legend of what which symbol in UML diagrams means).

Someone did a survey : A survey on the practical use of UML for different software architecture viewpoints

While the top popular viewpoints for the UML-based software
architecture modeling are the functional (96%) and information (99%)
viewpoints, the least popular one is the operational viewpoint that is
considered by 26% of the practitioners

So in the sample group, people like to use UML for functional diagrams, but not operational diagrams. This seems to support the idea that they would use different diagrams within the same document set.
Personally, I would say that most people reading these diagrams are not experts in UML or the various other diagram standards. They won't be reading it as a formal definition complex enough to convert into code, but as a explanatory picture of the how the solution works.
They won't care if you switch standards as long as the diagrams convey meaning.
The people that do look for the technical detail in the diagrams won't be fazed by a switch either. As long as you make a note of it.
NB: If you download the supplementary data you can see the break down of responses in each area including those that don't model the area at all. eg
I(we) do not use UML for modeling the software build process    30  55%
I(we) am/are not interested in modeling the build process        6  11%

Now we should note that this is just a survey of 109 people at the end of the day. But, it is exactly this kind of work which needs to be done to answer questions like yours.

"This seems to support the idea that they would use different diagrams within the same document set." - em, I don't think so. It supports the idea 75% don't use any UML diagrams for showing the operational viewpoint. Maybe those 75% use no diagrams at all. Maybe they use textual descriptions, maybe they think their systems don't require any operational description as part of their system's architecture documentation. But it definitely does not tell us anything about other types of diagrams.

that's why I say "supports" rather than "proves"

Not even close.

So your contention is that 100% of the "non UML" respondents don't draw any diagrams for that area of documentation? I mean... mayybeeeeeee. lets click download and see. hmm look like they break it out "we dont use UML..", "we are not interested in modeling..".

2% draw by hand!

No, my contention is that from a survey where the main question was "which UML diagrams do you use", and no question "which non-UML diagrams do you use" was asked, one should not jump to conclusions.

technically (the best kind) of correct, but the assumption that not using UML means some other diagram is used turned out to be safe.

I like this answer because, unlike most other answers on this site, this answer has a reference to a published scientific... anything. While this might not have the same scientific rigor to "prove" something, it does cast reasonable doubt on the premise of the question.

Indeed, this answer references a scientific article from a rigorously reviewed journal with a 3.9 impact factor. It's a solid evidence that comes close enough to what I was looking for. @GregBurghardt your answer is well structured and quiet convincing in its own right, and this is why I'm hesitating between the two.

Diagrams are only tools to express ideas, and you should always use tools that best suit your needs.  Some modeling languages, such as C4 even explicitly foresee a mix of diagrams, with high level block diagrams,  and UML and ERD for lower level of details.
For your specific subject on database modeling, I would however advise to carefully consider alternatives. You may of course be tempted to use different kind of diagrams for modelling different layers, with the following advantages:

an UML class diagram for an object oriented design, that you are implementing in your application, including behavioural aspects that ERD don't support;
an ERD for the flattening of your object oriented design into a relational implementation, with table-entities and relationship, that many db tools support.

However, not all the databases are relational, and ERD is not well suited for no-SQL databases, where UML offers more flexibility.  Moreover, at some moment you'll have to describe the Object-Relational Mapping and UML allows this easily, as demonstrated in Martin Fowler's Pattern of Enterprise Application Architecture in the chapters about object-relational patterns. Last but not least, UML is well suited for database modeling as well as you can express everything expressed in an ERD (example here), and there are even UML profiles that allow to express database details in a standard class diagram with more precision than ERD and the advantage of using only one set of homogeneous symbols (example: Scott Ambler's agile data modeling).
